# Breakpoints not being hit - VSCode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am very new to using VSCode, I am just trying to determine why my breakpoints are not being hit. I might be misunderstanding some basic concepts, so please bear with me.

I have a python file which is called by another python file.

In the python file that I want to debug, if I set a breakpoint at a top level indentation function it breaks, however, if I put a breakpoint in anything other than that the debugger skips over it.

[image: Doesnt Break]

[image: Does Break]

Comment: Open your primary python file and Go to Run->Start Debugging->Click **Python File**

Comment: This, unfortunately, is not the solution.
My launch.json correctly opens the intended file.

Comment: Can you share your code and gif about debugging? Because i test on my machine, the breakpoint can be triggered correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't executed your function `perform`. The interpreter walks over the function's definition first and stops correctly. The breakpoint inside the function is first seen by calling `perform`

Answer (score 0):

One way to troubleshoot is going to Debug Console in Vscode. It may give you a hint of why Debug and Break point did not hit.

In my case when debugging Django code calling other libraries, the break did not hit. Thanks to the suggestion in Debug Console, I changed `"justMyCode": false` to make it work.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqvuu.jpg)